# XSLT: How to compare attributes of different nodes within a for-each loop

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

I'm having some issues to compare two different attributes of two different nodes within a for-each loop.

Given this XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<test>
    <cars>
        <car id="1" color="blue" misc="4"/>
        <car id="2" color="red" misc="3"/>
        <car id="3" color="blue" misc="2"/>
        <car id="n" color="black" misc="1"/>
    </cars>
    <bikes>
        <bike id="1"/>
        <bike id="2"/>
        <bike id="3"/>
        <bike id="n"/>     
    </bikes>
</test>
```

XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
   xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <body>
                <h2>TEST - </h2>
                <xsl:variable name="bikes" select="test/bikes/bike"/>
                <xsl:variable name="cars" select="test/cars/car"/>
                <xsl:for-each select="$bikes">
                    <xsl:variable name="bikesID" select="./@id"/>
                    <xsl:for-each select="$cars">
                        <xsl:if test="$bikesID = ./@id">
                            <xsl:if test="./@color = 'blue'">
                                <xsl:value-of select="./@misc"/>
                            </xsl:if>
                        </xsl:if>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I want to compare the id of the bike and the car, if they are equals, then do a simple check with other car's attribute.. Please, see the expected result below.

> TEST - 4 2

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Cheers

> P.S.: The real issue was a wrong namespace by lack of attention. The
>   code is actually working fine, even if is not looking as good as could
>   be by using XPath/XSLT 2.0.

Comment: You didn't explain what problem you're running into while trying to do that. The code you're showing is already producing the result you want.

Comment: You actually show your expected output as "TEST - 4 1", but do you mean "TEST - 4 2", as these are the cars that are "blue"?

Comment: Sure, it should be TEST - 4 2. Thanks! @TimC

Comment: As Kumesana says, your current XSLT should produce the output your want. See http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/jyH9rMd. The only thing I can see might be the formatting (i.e. do you want a space between the numbers?). Can you say what output you are actually getting and how it differs from what you want? Thanks!

Comment: I thought it was a logic issue by spend a couple hours reading the real code and not getting the expected result. It was a wrong namespace by lack of attention. It's working fine now, thanks for your time! @TimC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see much wrong with your code, but in XSLT 2.0 if you want something less verbose you could write

```
<xsl:value-of select="for $bike in test/bikes/bike 
                      return test/cars/car[@id=$bike/@id]/@color"/>
```

Comment: Thanks! The code was right as you mentioned, the real issue was a wrong namespace by lack of attention. Anyway, I'll learn more about XSLT 2.0.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the inner loop over cars and can just replace it by an XPath expression for selecting the matching `misc` attribute directly:

```
<xsl:for-each select="test/bikes/bike">
  <xsl:variable name="id" select="@id"/>
  <xsl:value-of select="/test/cars/car[@id = $id and @color = 'blue']/@misc"/>
</xsl:for-each>
```